# GridView inside a Listview causing "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height" even when Expanded

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm still new to Flutter, and trying to create the following layout:

[image: eLayout Of What I'm trying to achieve]

I've split my layout into 3 main components:

1. The Title widget (the one with "Title Here")
2. The Info Text widget (the one with the Icon and "Info Goes Here"
   text)
3. The GridView containing the buttons <--- This one is causing the problem

Here is my Main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ifp_poc/Screens/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart' show debugPaintSizeEnabled;

void main() {
//  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Colors.blue,
        primaryColorLight: Colors.white,
        primaryColorDark: Colors.black,
        platform: Theme.of(context).platform,
      ),
      title: "POC",
      home: new Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Home Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ifp_poc/Components/ifp/listBoxHQ.dart';
import 'package:ifp_poc/Components/ifp/infoHQ.dart';
import 'package:ifp_poc/Components/ifp/titleHQ.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          new TitleHQ(
            logoAsset: "assets/images/HQ-LOGO.png",
            title: "Hospitality Qatar",
            subTitle: "06-08 Nov 2018",
            info: "3:00 PM - 9:00 PM",
            url: "http://www.ifpexpo.com",
          ),
          new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 26.0, right: 26.0),
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new InfoHQ(text: "Qatar's Premiere International Hospitlaity & Horeca Trade Show",),
                new Divider(height: 20.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,),
                new InfoHQ(text: "Doha Exhibition & Convention Centre (DECC)",icon: Icons.location_on,),
                new Divider(height: 20.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,),
                new ListBoxHQ()
              ],
            ),
          )

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my listBoxHQ() Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ifp_poc/Components/ifp/boxHQ.dart';

class ListBoxHQ extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListBoxHQState createState() => _ListBoxHQState();
}

class _ListBoxHQState extends State<ListBoxHQ> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GridView.count(
          primary: false,
          crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: <Widget>[
            BoxHQ(
              height: 100.0,
              text: "Overview",
              icon: Icons.ac_unit,
            ),
            BoxHQ(
              height: 100.0,
              text: "Overview",
              icon: Icons.ac_unit,
            ),
            BoxHQ(
              height: 100.0,
              text: "Overview",
              icon: Icons.ac_unit,
            ),
          ]
      );
  }
}
```

And Finally my BoxHQ Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BoxHQ extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;

  BoxHQ({Key key, @required this.height, @required this.icon, @required this.text}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _BoxHQState createState() => _BoxHQState();
}

class _BoxHQState extends State<BoxHQ> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: widget.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
      decoration:  new BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(10.0)),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: Column( // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(widget.icon == null? Icons.info : widget.icon, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight, size: 50.0,),
          new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0)),
          Text(widget.text, style: new TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight, fontSize: 20.0),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The Problem (TLDR) :**

When running the above code, I get the following error:

```
I/Choreographer( 6979): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation( 6979): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6cac080: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x970aa0c0)
I/flutter ( 6979): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6979): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter ( 6979): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 6979): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter ( 6979): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter ( 6979): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter ( 6979): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter ( 6979): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter ( 6979): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter ( 6979): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

**Things I've tried and did not work:**

- Adding *GridView.count* from *listBoxHQ* class inside an Expanded
- Adding every item of the Container from Home inside an Expanded
- Adding every child of the main column of Home inside an Expanded

It worked only when I wrapped the GridView.count of listBoxHQ with a SizedBox and fixed height. **But I can't do that as my buttons are dynamic and I don't know the number of buttons that I might have.**

I can't thank you enough for reading through everything, and I will be very grateful if you could share your knowledge with me and help me fix this issue.

Thanks a lot, for real!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should add this line of code inside your `GridView`:

```dart
shrinkWrap: true
```

So your GridView should looks like this:

```dart
return GridView.count(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  children: <Widget>[
    BoxHQ(
      height: 100.0,
      text: "Overview",
      icon: Icons.ac_unit,
    ),
    BoxHQ(
      height: 100.0,
      text: "Overview",
      icon: Icons.ac_unit,
    ),
    BoxHQ(
      height: 100.0,
      text: "Overview",
      icon: Icons.ac_unit,
    ),
  ]
);
```

This value forces `GridView` to occupy as much space, as its' children do. By default, `GridView` wants to fill all available space to provide scrolling through children when they doesn't fit all at once. In your scenario, the `GridView` wants to take all available height but its parent, `ListView` doesn't specify how much is available. It's because `ListView` itself wants to scroll the children if they doesn't fit, thus they can be as big as they want.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It worked and I would have never guessed if it wasn't for you and @anmol.majhail. Thanks a lot guys! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

In your GridView.count make shrinkWrap true.

```
......
return GridView.count(
    primary: false,
    shrinkWrap: true,
......
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It worked and I would have never guessed if it wasn't for you and @Jack Sun. Thanks a lot guys! Thank you!